# Getting started with Program Analysis

Tags: algorithm, compiler-construction, programming-languages, computer-science, semantics

I'm looking for resources on getting started with program analysis.

The only book I've found on the topic is the Nielson & Nielson book.

Other than that, it seems like there's only "compiler" books where "program analysis" would be a chapter, or something along those lines.

Do people know of any other resources? Thanks!

Comment: how about dissasembly? it's a great way to learn how the compiler translates into machine code. There is a great reverse engineering lecture: http://opensecuritytraining.info/IntroductionToReverseEngineering.html

Comment: A huge problem is getting tools that can read the programs, and reason about them at any level of capability.  For instance, how would you approach the problem of analyzing ColdFusion code for security flaws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Secure Programming with Static Analysis" might be useful.

There is a lecture series you might find useful as well
http://santos.cis.ksu.edu/schmidt/Escuela03/home.html